# String search with "startsWith()"

Tags: java, loops

I've been working on a email directory program for the past couple of day and in one of my methods I'm trying to make a search function that searches for an email based off the character inputs of the user.  I'm trying to make it to where the method loops and the user types in the email one character at a time until only one email is in the array i constructed for this method.

Heres my code:

```
private void searchContact()    
{
    String[] newRecords=new String[emailRecords.size()];        //temp array for searching
    ArrayList<String> searchRecords=new ArrayList<String>();    //to be passed to insertion sort
    newRecords=emailRecords.toArray(newRecords);                

    for(String Records: newRecords) 
    {
        Scanner search=new Scanner(System.in);                  //setup for user input
        String letter;
        String searchVal;

        System.out.println("Please enter the first letter of the email you're trying to find.");
        letter=search.nextLine();

        if (searchRecords.size()!=1)    
        {   
            for (int i=0; i<newRecords.length;i++)          //counter for indexes
            {
                searchVal=newRecords[i];                        //set temp value to set index

                if (searchVal.startsWith(letter))               //starts with boolean
                {
                    searchRecords.add(searchVal);               //add to temp array for later comparison
                }
            }
        }
        else    
        {
            break;                                              //break if one remains in the array.
        }
    }
    System.out.println(searchRecords);                          //TODO erase when finalizing
}
```

And here's what happens when i run the program entering names starting with the same letter:

```
Please enter the number of your option choice:
1. Add a new contact
2. Search for an exsisting contact
3. Exit
1
Please enter the email adress.
mark
***mark was successfully stored.***
Please enter the number of your option choice:
1. Add a new contact
2. Search for an exsisting contact
3. Exit
1
Please enter the email adress.
mike
***mike was successfully stored.***
Please enter the number of your option choice:
1. Add a new contact
2. Search for an exsisting contact
3. Exit
1
Please enter the email adress.
molly
***molly was successfully stored.***
Please enter the number of your option choice:
1. Add a new contact
2. Search for an exsisting contact
3. Exit
2
Please enter the first letter of the email you're trying to find.
m
Please enter the first letter of the email you're trying to find.
a
Please enter the first letter of the email you're trying to find.
r
[mark, mike, molly]
Please enter the number of your option choice:
1. Add a new contact
2. Search for an exsisting contact
3. Exit
```

And here my expected output after I enter in the information and try to search for "mark" by entering "m", "a", "r", and "k":

```
Please enter the next letter of the email you're trying to find.
m
Please enter the next letter of the email you're trying to find.
a
Please enter the next letter of the email you're trying to find.
r
Please enter the next letter of the email you're trying to find.
k
[mark]
```

I tried to make another for loop on the outside of the other that also counts and use it to move the index of the given string but it failed.  I feel like I'm close but overlooking something.  Any advise or strategies will be greatly appreciated!  Thanks a million.

Comment: Thanks for that edit. What output do you expect? I guess it should ask for more letters if it finds more than one mail?

Comment: In your code: `for (int i=0; i<newRecords.length-1;i++) ` I think you may want to remove the `-1` to loop through the whole thing.  Can you please describe your problem?

Comment: To make it more clear, can you add another block that contains the expected output of a search after you've added the four records? Like in your current ouput, where you entered `"2"`, but with the expected results. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `emailRecords` contains all of your emails, your task is something like:

```
private void searchContact() {
    assert(!(emailRecords == null || emailRecords.isEmpty()));// :P
    //initially copy all
    ArrayList<String> searchRecords = new ArrayList<>(emailRecords);
    //prepare scanner
    Scanner search = new Scanner(System.in);
    //initialize query
    String query = "";
    //loop:
    while (searchRecords.size() > 1) {
        System.out.println("Please enter the first letter of the email you're trying to find.");
        //read from input
        query += search.nextLine();
        //iterate through remaining searchRecords
        for (Iterator<String> it = searchRecords.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
            final String entry = it.next();
            if (!entry.startsWith(query)) {//...conditionally
                it.remove();//..remove (from searchRecords)
            }
        }
    }
    //print output - first/last of searchRecords
    if (!searchRecords.isEmpty())
        System.out.println(searchRecords.get(0));
    else
        System.out.println("No record found.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing you might try is using a **trie** data structure to store the e-mail addresses. "A common application of a trie is storing a predictive text or autocomplete dictionary ..." from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie.